# Making the while loop del guess from card[list]

Tags: python, list, while-loop, python-3.4, del

```
import random  
card = ['ace of spades', 'two of spades', 'three of spades', 'four of spades',  
    'five of spades', 'six of spades', 'seven of spades',  
    'eight of spades', 'nine of spades', 'ten of spades',  
    'jack of spades', 'queen of spades', 'king of spades',  
    'ace of clubs', 'two of clubs', 'three of clubs', 'four of clubs',  
    'five of clubs', 'six of clubs', 'seven of clubs',  
    'eight of clubs', 'nine of clubs', 'ten of clubs',  
    'jack of clubs', 'queen of clubs', 'king of clubs',  
    'ace of hearts', 'two of hearts', 'three of hearts', 'four of hearts',  
    'five of hearts', 'six of hearts', 'seven of hearts',  
    'eight of hearts', 'nine of hearts', 'ten of hearts',  
    'jack of hearts', 'queen of hearts', 'king of hearts',  
    'ace of diamonds', 'two of diamonds', 'three of diamonds', 'four of diamonds',  
    'five of diamonds', 'six of diamonds', 'seven of diamonds',  
    'eight of diamonds', 'nine of diamonds', 'ten of diamonds',  
    'jack of diamonds', 'queen of diamonds', 'king of diamonds']  
answer = input('Pick a card:\n')  
guess = random.choice(card)  
guesses = 1  
while guess != answer:  
    if guess != card:  
        guess = random.choice(card)  
        print(guess)  
    guesses += 1  
print('\nWhoopy, I guessed right!\n')  
print('It only took me %s guesses to guess %s.' % (guesses, answer))
```

So this is the code I have. I was attempting to add to the if statement... del card[:guess], but I know it needs an integer. How can I turn the guess into an integer and then del from list so it doesn't dupe guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the item from the list `card.remove(guess)`:

```
answer = input('Pick a card:\n')
guess = random.choice(card)
guesses = 1
while guess != answer:
    if guess != card:            
        guess = random.choice(card)
        card.remove(guess)
    guesses += 1
print('\nWhoopy, I guessed right!\n')
print('It only took me %s guesses to guess %s.' % (guesses, answer))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

use the "Index" method of a list to get the index of the item:

```
card.index(guess)
```

Or make your random choice pick an index instead of an element:

```
guess = random.choice(range(len(card)))
```

As some other answer pointed out though, you don't need to get the actual index to accomplish this task

Comment: Thanks!! I see that now. Both answers are helpful. But the card.remove(guess) is definitely the way to go.

Comment: In the latter case you could just use `random.randrange(len(card))`